# When I create a virtualenv, python runs in 64-bit even when already set to 32-bit in OSX

Tags: python, macos, 32bit-64bit, virtualenv, mysql-python

My setup is: 2.6.1 python (apple default, snow leopard), virtualenv, and using virtualenvwrapper

Outside the environment, everything runs in 32-bit which is fine. But with a new project I'm going to work on needs django 1.3 and tons of dependencies, so I made a virtualenv.

I've managed to install everything well, except that mysql-python (via pip) gets an error of "mach -o wrong architecture". I've checked my python interpreter with "import sys; sys.maxint" inside the virtualenv and python runs in 64-bit.

I've already set systemwide for python to run in 32-bit via "defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes"

Does anyone know why this happens inside the virtualenv?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much of the "magic" that Apple used to implement their `Prefer-32-bit` for the system Pythons in OS X 10.6 is in `/usr/bin/python` which then calls the real Python interpreters which are symlinked at `/usr/bin/python2.6` and `/usr/bin/python2.5`.  `virtualenv` copies the real interpreter into the virtualenv `bin` directory so the `Prefer-32-bit` processing is bypassed.

Among the options to ensure 32-bit operation:

1. Use the `arch` command to invoke the interpreter.

   ```
   $ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 ./p
   $ ./p/bin/python -c 'import sys;print(sys.maxsize)'
   9223372036854775807
   $ arch -i386 ./p/bin/python -c 'import sys;print(sys.maxsize)'
   2147483647
   ```
2. Use `lipo` to extract only the 32-bit arch from the universal binary.

   ```
   $ file ./p/bin/python
   ./p/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
   ./p/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
   ./p/bin/python (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
   ./p/bin/python (for architecture ppc7400):  Mach-O executable ppc
   $ cp ./p/bin/python ./p/bin/python-universal
   $ lipo ./p/bin/python-universal -thin i386 -output ./p/bin/python
   $ file ./p/bin/python
   ./p/bin/python: Mach-O executable i386
   $ ./p/bin/python -c 'import sys;print(sys.maxsize)'
   2147483647
   ```
3. Install and use a newer 32-bit-only Python 2.6 or 2.7 (installers available from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/))

Comment: Thanks for this.

I've done the second option (using lipo) for the executable in the virtualenv as using arch commands doesn't work in running the django mini server (arch -i386 python manage.py runserver) for some unknown reason.

Comment: Yes, the `arch` trick won't work if the program you run spawns other Python processes via `subprocess`, et al, so using `lipo` or a 32-bit-only Python are safer.